# CSS, Trouble aligning divs in chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome

Im having a mysterious problem with some positioning in chrome.
Its about one of my pages: http://www.iphonedeksler.no/

The div to the right, with `class="content"`, is too far down in chrome, but perfect in firefox and IE.

Whats adding to the mystery, is that when you inspect, and toggle the "float:right;" css rule off, and then on again, it aligns like it should.

Is this a chrome bug, and should I use css hack for chrome only?

Comment: looks good to me - you should add a clear after that div though - <br class="clear" />

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that `.main { clear: both; }` is messing up the `.content` div alignment.
If you remove `clear: both` you will solve the alignment problem.